# gawk 'NR==$i....statement not working

Tags: shell, gawk

I have the following shell script code. Here if I'm using `NR==$i` in `gawk` statement, it doesn't work, while if I simply use `NR==1` (or some other integer value) it works perfectly fine.

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))
 do
    gawk 'NR==$i{//some action}' input.txt
done
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the single quotes around the `awk` script mean that `bash` does no substitution inside the string and `gawk` sees literally `$i` (which is the same as `$0` since `i` is not initialized in the `gawk` script).

This time, use double quotes instead:

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))
do
    gawk "NR==$i{//some action}" input.txt
done
```

In general, it would probably be better to pass the variable explicitly:

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))
do
    gawk -v i=$i 'NR==i{//some action}' input.txt
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with that is that you are using simple quotes (`'`) around you gawk script, and within that `bash` does not replaces the value of `$i`, so try double quotes (`"`) instead.